# Application of grid view in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

There are some Forms and some Custom User controls (custom drop down window containing dataGridView ) in my project.in a Form(Purchase order) have a dataGridView control, when clicking a cell this custom dropdown window will appear, when selecting a row in that drop down window or by clicking ENTER key these values (ie, cell values  in a row of gridview) sholud moves to previous grid view of FORM. I tried this, can't get expected output...any one helpe...

### portion of code in custom user control:-

```
#region Declarations
    public string grdItmName;
    public string grdItmDisrption;
    public string grdItmCata;
    public string grdItmPrice;
    #endregion

    #region prop
    public string gridfield1
    {
        get
        {
            return grdItmName;
        }
        set { grdItmName = value; }
    }

    public string gridfield2
    {
        get
        {
            return grdItmDisrption;
        }
        set { grdItmDisrption = value; }
    }
    public string gridfield3
    {
        get
        {
            return grdItmCata;
        }
        set { grdItmCata = value; }
    }
    public string gridfield4
    {
        get
        {
            return grdItmPrice;
        }
        set { grdItmPrice = value; }
    }
#endregion
```

---

```
private void gridItemlist_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))
        {

            try
            {
                grdItmName = gridItemlist.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                grdItmDisrption = gridItemlist.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                grdItmCata = gridItemlist.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                grdItmPrice = gridItemlist.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


}
```

---

code snippets of FORM grid view:--

```
private void gridPrchaseOrder_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)

{


customDropDown.Show();
customDropDown.BringToFront();`// display in front of other controls`
customDropDown.Select();
customDropDown.Location = gridPrchaseOrder.PointToScreen(gridPrchaseOrder.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false).Location);




        try
        {   
          int n = gridPrchaseOrder.Rows.Add();
          gridPrchaseOrder.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = customDropDown.gridfield1;
            gridPrchaseOrder.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = customDropDown.gridfield2;
            gridPrchaseOrder.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = customDropDown.gridfield3;
            gridPrchaseOrder.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = customDropDown.gridfield4;
            customDropDown.Focus();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One observation, in the user/custom control Remove the above shown code and declare the properties with names as below. You don't require gridfield1, gridfield2, gridfield3 and gridfield4. Its not a good practice to have such variable names.

```
public string grdItmName { get; set; }
public string grdItmDisrption { get; set; }
public string grdItmCata { get; set; }
public string grdItmPrice { get; set; }
```

Now in the form code

```
        try
        {   
          int n = gridPrchaseOrder.Rows.Add();
          gridPrchaseOrder.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = customDropDown.grdItmName;
            gridPrchaseOrder.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = customDropDown.grdItmDisrption;
            gridPrchaseOrder.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = customDropDown.grdItmCata;
            gridPrchaseOrder.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = customDropDown.grdItmPrice;
            customDropDown.Focus();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
```

Comment: code for pass a grid view  selected row's cells value to another form's grid view row.

Comment: On gridPrchaseOrder_CellMouseClick() you display the usercontrol. When/where are you hiding it ? Assuming you are doing this on the Ok button in user control, then here, pass on the values to the gridPrchaseOrder in a new row. While you are passing the values as soon as user control is shown, which seems incorrect.
Please provide the code where you are making user control hidden.